# Explode column of objects python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl, pandas-explode

I am trying to explode a column to create new rows within pandas data frame. What would be the best approach to this?

Input:

| SKU | Quantity | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YY-123-671 | 5 | drawer |
| YY-345-111-WH,YY-345-111-RD,YY-345-111-BL | 10 | desk |
| LK-896-001 | 1 | lamp |

Desired Output:

| SKU | Quantity | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YY-123-671 | 5 | drawer |
| YY-345-111-WH | 10 | desk |
| YY-345-111-RD | 10 | desk |
| YY-345-111-BL | 10 | desk |
| LK-896-001 | 1 | lamp |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.assign(SKU=df['SKU'].str.split(',')).explode('SKU')
```

`result`:

```
    SKU             Quantity    Name
0   YY-123-671      5           drawer
1   YY-345-111-WH   10          desk
1   YY-345-111-RD   10          desk
1   YY-345-111-BL   10          desk
2   LK-896-001      1           lamp
```